# Saving a video offline while playing in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am able to play the videos in exoplayer using the source code at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer, but unable to find, how to save video and play later while offline.

Also how segmented videos running through mpd files will be saved offline?

Any code snippet that I can put inside the exoplayer source code to make it work would be highly appreciable.

[image: segmented video file]

Comment: [refer this link for video caching](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CacheDataSource](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/9f814850535afbe5a0123f7fa8fc2875ba2c5015/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/cache/CacheDataSource.java) and wrap your data source with it (eg. wrap the DefaultHttpDataSource).